# Scrolling não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um problema em um site que estou criando, o efeito de rolagem que fiz no Js não está funcionando corretamente, eu coloquei um console.log() para saber se ao menos o evento está executando e está, o único problema é que o scroll não acontece. Se puderem me ajudar a gradeço.

MENU

```
<ul class="navbar-menu">
   <li><a class="scrolling" href="#home">MENU 1</a></li>
   <li><a class="scrolling" href="#portfolio">MENU 2</a></li>
   <li><a class="scrolling" href="#videos">MENU 3</a></li>
   <li><a class="scrolling" href="#contact">MENU 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.scrolling').click(function (e) {
       var linkHref = $(this).attr('href');
       console.log($(linkHref).offset().top);
       $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(linkHref).offset().top
       }, 1000);
       e.preventDefault();
      });
  });
```

P.S: Minha versão do jquery é a 3.1.1.

Se precisarem de mais informações por favor me digam.

Abraço.

Comment: Poste o resto do html por favor

Comment: Eu reproduzi seu código nesse [fiddle ](https://jsfiddle.net/awxtcdm3/)
Está funcionando corretamente. Verifique se você definiu os ids corretamente nos elementos que você quer atingir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente você alterou o `oveflow:;` do `body, html` ou adicionou um novo overflow para um elemento dentro do `body`, veja que o seu código funciona bem aqui:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.scrolling').click(function (e) {
        var linkHref = $(this).attr('href');

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(linkHref).offset().top
        }, 1000);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 240px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="navbar-menu">
    <li><a class="scrolling" href="#home">MENU 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="scrolling" href="#portfolio">MENU 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="scrolling" href="#videos">MENU 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="scrolling" href="#contact">MENU 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home" class="box"></div>
<div id="portfolio" class="box"></div>
<div id="videos" class="box"></div>
<div id="contact" class="box"></div>
```

Se um elemento dentro de body tiver um scroll proprio você deverá trocar o `html,body` do seletor, assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.scrolling').click(function (e) {
        var linkHref = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#main').animate({ //TROCADO
            scrollTop: $(linkHref).offset().top
        }, 1000);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 240px;
    background: #00f;
}
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
#main {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
    <ul class="navbar-menu">
        <li><a class="scrolling" href="#home">MENU 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="scrolling" href="#portfolio">MENU 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="scrolling" href="#videos">MENU 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="scrolling" href="#contact">MENU 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="home" class="box"></div>
    <div id="portfolio" class="box"></div>
    <div id="videos" class="box"></div>
    <div id="contact" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Guilherme boa tarde. Você está corretíssimo eu adicionei(não sei porque um overflow:auto no body/html). Removi isto e tudo está de acordo agora! Agradeço novamente amigão, abraço!

Comment: @JhonathanSilva por nada ;)